# Isshin, the Sword Saint phase 2 no spear

Tags: sekiro-shadows-die-twice

As can be seen in [this speedrun](https://youtu.be/sgR9W4gwVjY?t=3019) it is possible to stop Isshin to draw the spear in his second phase (and presumably also 3rd phase).

**The question is, how can I achieve that? Do I constantly need to stagger him, or what exactly do I need to do to stop him from drawing the spear?**

---

My best try so far, was stopping him around 3-4 times using the Long Spark, but this just didn't cut it. After that he still drew the spear, so this does not seem to be the right way to do it.

As the comments on the video are mostly in chinese (so I guess), I have no means to see if anyone actually explains that tactic there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After phase one, continue to attack before he transforms until he parries. Once he parries he goes into basic retaliations from his first phase. If you are good enough and he doesn't manage to get too far away from you, you can keep on him and keep continuing to force him into block stun and eventually a parry until you get another deathblow.

If at any point he gets far enough away from you or there is a lull in your assault he will do the animation to go into his spear (and lightning form for phase 3).

Comment: When experimenting with this myself, I found the animation for the phase change will sometimes play regardless of how much you attack Isshin. It appears that in the video when the phase change animation begins to play the player uses the firecracker prosthetic three times in order to stagger Isshin which allows the phase change animation to be skipped, though I have not replicated this myself.

Comment: @MichaelHolland I just reviewed the scene and it seems that he just took 3 tries to get the right timing to get Isshin to parry again. I guess that 1 single firecracker could be sufficient enough. I will test this as soon as I have time to do so

Comment: @MichaelHolland You're right, the firecrackers are also an option here but I wasn't able to successfully use them but I read about this tactic on reddit.

Comment: I tried the tactic yesterday, but were only successful to some extent. I could stop him for some time, but not the whole phase. Also it is necessary to attack from the front, as attacks from the back (and side I think) don't get him to parry